# override block "content"

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

How to override block named "content" from page.xml? Am I doing it right? Cause below code not return expected value.

\app\code\local\Trening\NewModule\controllers\IndexController.php:

```
class Trening_NewModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function sayHelloAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

\app\code\local\Trening\NewModule\etc\config.xml:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <trening_newmodule>
                <use>standard</use> 
                <args>
                    <module>Trening_NewModule</module>
                    <frontName>trening</frontName> 
                </args>
            </trening_newmodule>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <newmodule>
                    <file>trening.xml</file>
                </newmodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

\app\design\frontend\default\trening\layout\trening.xml:

```
<layout>
    <trening_newmodule_index_sayhello>
        <reference name="content">
                <block type="newmodule/product" name="newmodule" template="trening/myproducts.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </trening_newmodule_index_sayhello>
</layout>
```

\app\design\frontend\default\trening\template\trening\myproducts.phtml:

```
<h1>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
<?php echo $this->getProducts(); ?>
```

\app\code\local\Trening\NewModule\Block\Product.php:

```
class Trening_NewModule_Block_Product extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return "it works!;";
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

- dashboard/admin/configuration/design Package_Name: rwd, Themes :blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have "trening" theme set as default, otherwise keep FE files in base/default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace code in ,

```
app\design\frontend\default\trening\layout\trening.xml:

<layout>
    <trening_newmodule_index_sayhello>
        <reference name="content">
                <block type="newmodule/product" name="newmodule" template="trening/myproducts.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </trening_newmodule_index_sayhello>
</layout>
```

With

```
<layout>
    <trening_index_sayhello>
        <reference name="content">
                <block type="newmodule/product" name="newmodule" template="trening/myproducts.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </trening_index_sayhello>
</layout>
```

And change your controller,

```
app\code\local\Trening\NewModule\controllers\IndexController.php

class Trening_NewModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function sayhelloAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: removed `newmodule` and lower case controller action name. Still the same unfortunately.

Comment: try with caching and then check. verify code one's.

Comment: try/catching $this->loadLayout() in controller?

Comment: Magento caching from admin or remove cache folder from Magento Root/var/cache.

Comment: im in no-cache mode, all time